# Populate TTTableViewController with JSON data

Tags: three20

Hi can't find any simple tutorial/doc on how to populate a TTTableViewController with remote JSON data through a data model.

I followed this tutorial to create my Table View with local datas: http://www.raywenderlich.com/656/introduction-to-three20

To populate a photo gallery with remote data, I used this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer and it works great. But I can't reproduce it for the tableView !

If somebody know a good tutorial on "How to populate a TTTableViewController with remote JSON", please let me know !

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Three20 Samples https://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/samples/, the TTTwitter sample app uses a `TTURLRequestModel` to populate a `TTTableViewController` with remote JSON data retrieved from Twitter.